# How to align text in a list element with the next one below?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web, frontend

[image]

As you can see the text is not in line with the text below. I am using justify-content: space-between for this, and think this is the problem but I can't think of a solution.

```
    <style>

        li {
            list-style-type: none;
            background: cornflowerblue;
            margin: 50px auto;
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            width: 1000px;
            justify-content:space-between;
        }

        ul {
            margin-left: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

    </style>
```

```
            <ul>
                <li v-for="project in projectsInfo">
                    <h3>{{ project.title }}</h3>
                    <h3>{{ project.date }}</h3>
                    <h3>{{ project.role }}</h3>
                    <h3>{{ project.visits }}</h3>
                    <h3 :href='project.link'>GAME LINK</h3>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: A list is not the suitable tool for that job. In almost all cases you would use [a table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) for that.

Comment: While they are correct, you should use a table for this, you can achieve the same effect by adding `width` and `max-width` to each of your `<h3></h3>` elements and the parent `<li>`

Comment: @bassxzero: Yes, you could simply say: `li h3 { width: 20%; }` and that will work, but it will lack the flexibility of a HTML table. It's not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using table would be better approach to achieve such scenario. Although, try with giving fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify a width for each inner column inside a li element:

```
li {
        list-style-type: none;
        background: cornflowerblue;
        margin: 50px auto;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 1000px;
        justify-content:space-between;
        
        > * {                   
          &:nth-child(1) {
            width:20%
          }
          &:nth-child(2) {
            width:25%
          }
          &:nth-child(3) {
            width:35%
          }
          &:nth-child(4) {
            width:20%;
            text-align:right;
          }              
        }
       }
```

Comment: Hello, before you wrote this I turned it into a table. The table was all aligned when I hardcoded in the table contents, but since I've used a Vue for loop to implement it, it's gone out of alignment again. Have you got any idea what the issue is?

[image of table](https://pasteboard.co/AfpAoWVkFyXd.png)
[JS File contents](https://pasteboard.co/cf6BcbcHpSga.png)
[HTML File contents](https://pasteboard.co/61zYtUeNJRvN.png)

Comment: what do you mean turning into a column? flex-direction:column?

Comment: sorry, i meant turned it into a table.

Comment: then specify a width for each td in a row 
td:nth-child(1) {
            width:20%
          }
          td:nth-child(2) {
            width:25%
          }, etc...

Comment: thank you very much for your help, this was driving me crazy